# Strange artifacting on screen

Tags: macbook-pro, display

For a while now been getting these strange artefacts on my MBP (mid 2010) screen.  Usually happens when I cmd + tab to another window.  Most of the time it's yellow in color, however sometimes it's red/green/black.  If I move the window or cmd + tab again it will go away.  Also happens on external display through the MDP

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it probably indicates a video hardware problem.  More than once, when I have started seeing video artifacts, hardware failure follows.

Comment: Yea I'm still under applecare but cant really lose my machine for the 7 business days they want to fix it

Comment: I've had good luck using a local Mac shop that can perform Applecare repairs.  A couple of times they have confirmed the problem and ordered the parts.  I brought the machine back when the parts arrived.  In both cases the repair was 1-2 days not 7.  Good luck.